# Jenkins-Declarative Pipeline - How to make particular stage failure

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In my Jenkins declarative pipeline I am performing small validation on Patchnumber being passed in the job parameter. If the patch number is less than 8 Chars, the particular stage should fail. Below is the code for the same. Here I see the Stage is not failing and it proceeds with the next Stage.

How can I make the Stage fail forcefully and terminate the whole Job  execution?

```groovy
stage("Validate Patch Number Size")
{
    steps
    {
        script
        {
            if ( (params.ENGLISH_PATCH_NUMBER).length() == 8 && (params.BIP_DB_PATCH_NUMBER).length() == 8 && (params.KO_PATCH_NUMBER).length() == 8) {
                result = 'valid'
                echo "Patch number entered meets the recommended size 8 - Status:$result"
            } else {
                resultStatus = 'Invalid'
                echo "The patch number size doesnt meet the recommended size 8 - Status: $resultStatus "
                currentBuild.result='FAILURE'
                echo "The current status is ${currentBuild.result}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`error` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#error-error-signal) to output a message and abort the pipeline. This marks the current stage aswell as the whole pipeline as failed (assuming there is no `catchError` or `try/catch` on a higher level).

You don't need to set `currentBuild.result` manually.

```groovy
else {
    resultStatus = 'Invalid'
    error "The patch number size doesnt meet the recommended size 8 - Status: $resultStatus"
    // No further code will be executed after 'error'!
}
```